# Like button does not display the comment box

Tags: facebook-like, share

I use the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function() {
       document.write('<fb:like data-href="MY_SITE" class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="stardant" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-action="like" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="verdana"><\/fb:like>');
       var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'), s1 =document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
       s.type = 'text/javascript';
           s.async = true;
       s.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1';
       s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
   })();
   //]]>
   </script>
```

The problem is when you click the button, the comment box is not displayed, but the LIKE works normal, appear on my profile. I need this code because it is valid XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should be data-layout="standard" instead of stardant. Data-layout is a valid FB property?

And 2nd: If you have an old vers on IE and want to use  you have to add an XML namespace to html tag:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```